# The name Count does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, winforms, scope

This method is part of a class called OSVersion. When I test this in a console application though it works fine. Count does not exist in the current context. Can anyone shed some light on this please.

```
public static bool  OperatingSystemVersionGet()
        {
            XmlDocument xlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            string sfile =
                @"C:\dev\4.6\RTM\R1\Install\SetupManager\SourceCode.SetupManager\SourceCode.SetupManager\Configs\blackpearl\Product.config";

            xlDoc.Load(sfile);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xlDoc.SelectNodes("//dependancy");

            List<string> compareList = new List<string>();

            string osv = Environment.OSVersion.VersionString;

            int firstIndex = osv.IndexOf(' ');
            int secondIndex = osv.IndexOf(' ', firstIndex + 1);
            int thirdIndex = osv.IndexOf(' ', secondIndex + 1);

            String osName = osv.Substring(0, thirdIndex);
            String majorVersion = osv.Substring(thirdIndex + 1, 1);
            String minorVersion = osv.Substring(thirdIndex + 3, 1);

            bool isIn = false;

            if (nodeList != null)
                foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                {
                    try
                    {

                            string type = node.Attributes["type"].Value;
                            string name = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
                            string feat = node.Attributes["featureversion"].Value;

                            String[] versionPart = feat.Split('.');

                            string second = versionPart[1];
                            string third = versionPart[2];

                                if (type == "Windows")
                                {
                                    if((name == osName) && ((second == majorVersion) && (third == minorVersion)))
                                    {
                                        compareList.Add(name);
                                    }

                                }


                    }
                    catch(NullReferenceException ex)
                    {
                        //nullReferenceException handled here
                    }
                }

           if(compareList.Count == 0)
            {
                isIn = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isIn = false;
            }
            return isIn;

        }
```

Comment: I do not see where you initialize compareList. However, it looks as if you're attempting to access the `Count` element of the list `compareList`. Where you looking for `.size()` instead?

Comment: I see no issues, except that the return can be just "return compareList.Count > 0"

Comment: @PenguinCoder: He initializes `compareList` on line 10, and `Count` is the correct property of a `List`. There is no `size` method, however.

Comment: @AdamCrossland That is what I get for not seeing this was a Winforms question!

Comment: Are you seeing this error at runtime or compile time?

Comment: @AdamCrossland I receive this in compile time.

Comment: @p0enkie : I make a copy of your function in my current project and I compile it without error !

Comment: try to clean your project and rebuild your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you say that you receive this in compile time

try to clean your solution and rebuild it .

I can't see any error and  I made a copy of your function in my current project and I compile it without error !

Comment: Some method in the project was continuously over writing my xml file. After tweaking that a bit, this method seems to work fine. Makes no sense to me, but hey it works now. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly missing a `using System.Collections.Generic` at the top of your source file for your winforms app.